# Warning from keras: "Update your Conv2D call to the Keras 2 API"

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to use keras to create a CNN, but I keep getting this warning which I do not understand how to fix.

> Update your `Conv2D` call to the Keras 2 API: `Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation="relu")` after removing the cwd from sys.path.

Can anyone give any ideas about fixing this?

Comment: can you provide code?

Answer (score 5):

As it says, it's not an issue. It still works fine although they might change it any day and the code will not work.

In Keras 2 `Convolution2D` has been replaced by `Conv2d` along with some changes in the parameters.

> Convolution* layers are renamed Conv*.
>
> Conv2D(10, 3, 3) becomes Conv2D(10, (3, 3))

Answer (score 2):

In keras 2

convolution2D is changed into Conv2d or Conv2D

So use:

```
from keras.layers import Conv2D instead of **from keras.layers import Convolution2D

classifier.add(Conv2D(32,( 3, 3), input_shape = (64, 64, 3), activation = 'relu')) instead of classifier.add(Conv2D(32,3, 3, input_shape = (64, 64, 3), activation = 'relu'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Keras 2 came with some API changes.. The old API is still works, but would give you a warning stating that the new API functioning don't use Convolutional*, as you see in your code.

`Convolution2D` is now `Conv2d`

You can read about the other API changes here https://github.com/fchollet/keras/wiki/Keras-2.0-release-notes

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation="relu")
```

The problem is you have not written `kernel_size`, i.e

```
Conv2D(64, kernel_size = (3,3), activation="relu")
```